# Unable to upload a json file in same syntax to Amazon SQS using Python BOTO

Tags: python, json, amazon-sqs

My json file looks like :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

I am using the following boto code to upload this to Amazon SQS

```
import json
import uuid
import time
import boto.sqs
import boto
import glob
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage


def process_file(json_file):
        sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")
        queue = sqs.get_queue("Killswitch")
        with open(json_file) as json_fileone:
                dataone=json.load(json_fileone)
                print dataone
                [queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in dataone]
                print "File sent successfully to queue"

json_files = glob.glob("*json")
for json_file in json_files:
    process_file(json_file)
```

This code works fine, but when I check my SQS queue via AWS console on browser, I see **4 messages** instead of one single message consisting on this json file..

And when I try to read the same via boto code I end up receiving the following :

```
id 
name 
price 
tags
```

I need to upload the whole file in one single message and not as 4 objects/**messages**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in this line:

```
[queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in dataone]
```

`for i in dataone` means you are iterating the keys of the json objects

You are effectively doing

```
queue.write(queue.new_message('id')) 
queue.write(queue.new_message('name')) 
queue.write(queue.new_message('price')) 
queue.write(queue.new_message('tags'))
```

Apparently the API only accepts string, you can try:

```
    with open(json_file) as json_fileone:
            dataone=json_fileone.read()
            queue.write(queue.new_message(dataone))
            print "File sent successfully to queue"
```

Comment: What error? People on SO can't help if there is not enough information

Comment: It throws a error Traceback (most recent call last): value = value.encode('utf-8') AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode' 


and i have a couple of json files to upload

Comment: The API expects a string. i.e. you don't need to apply json.load to the file content

Comment: I did this , 
 with open(json_file) as json_fileone:
                queue.write(queue.new_message(json_fileone))
                print "File sent successfully to queue"
still throws :
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Don't pass the file object to the API directly. You still need to read from the file. See the updated answer.